# Custom field normalization

Tags: apex, custom-field

I have created a custom field of type Text Area in my Sandbox environment and would like to know how to normalize the text typed into this custom field.

In order to make a normalization I've implememted the following method:

```
public String domainNormalization(Account accountObj) {
    String domain = accountObj.Domain__c;
    if (domain != null) {
        domain = domain.replaceAll('[ ]+', '');
        domain = domain.replaceAll('[,;:*]+', ' ');
        domain = domain.replaceAll('(https?://www.|https?|www.)', ' ');
        domain = domain.replaceAll('(A-Za-z\\d._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&\'()*+,;=-)', ' ');
        accountObj.Domain__c = domain;
        return domain;
    }
    return '';
}
```

But when I am able to add in the domain field: [image: Screenshot 1]

The code in the normalization method does not work because I get the following:
[image: Screennshot 2]

It should always look for string(domainname) + dot "." + the extension of the domain(com, eu, bg and etc). Where the separator between these must be a single space for example: domain.com secondomain.com thirddomain.com

Coud you please advise how to normalize the text typed in the domain field in order to achive the same result in the given example?

I also would like to know is there a way to get all possible domain extensions(com, eu, bg and etc)? Do I need special consideration about domains such as for instance (co.uk)?

Comment: Don't you have to escape the `*` character?

Comment: I have used the following regex ('(A-Za-z\\d._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&\'()*+,;=-)', ' '); which indeed escape the asterisk character but still can't normalize the text typed in the domain field and get the result I want. Here is the what I get after the asterisk charatcter is escaped:

Comment: ha ha.hatest omg testdomain.comseconddomain.comthriddomain.com

Comment: The result I want to get is the following:

Comment: testdomain.comseconddomain.comthriddomain.com

Comment: to remain in the field

Comment: Could you please advise or which is even more appropriate could you please include an example code how this can be achieved?

Comment: Please do not spam the comment thread with updates. If you have additional information, please add it using the [Edit] button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you expect this string to contain, but it seems to me that you may be making this much more difficult than it needs to be. I would suggest you try doing something like this:

```
public String domainNormalization(Account accountObj) {
    String domain = accountObj.Domain__c;
    if (domain != null) {
        domain = domain.normalizeSpace();
        // removes all leading, trailing and repeating whitespace

        // If there's no '.' in the string that follows the domain
        domain = domain.substringAfterLast(.);

        //* ***If the the domain doesn't follow the last period***

        domain = domain.remove('http|https|:|\/\/|www.');

        domain = domain.remove(',|;');
        // no need to insert a space, just remove

        // in doing the below it seems you'd be removing content from wrong places
        // domain = domain.replaceAll('(A-Za-z\\d._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&\'()*+,;=-)', ' ');
        // it seems the thing to do now is to use split and count the number of returned 
        list<string>domainparts = domain.split('.');

        if(domainparts.size()>2){
        // you need to figure out which one of the strings has what you're looking for and remove the '.' from the end of it

        else if(domainparts.size()==1){
           domain = domainparts[1];
           //double check to make certain it doesn't end with a period
           if(domainparts[1].endsWith('.')) domain = domainparts[1].removeEnd('.'); 
        }

        ***//

      accountObj.Domain__c = domain;
      return domain;
    }
    return ;
}
```

And yes, if you have multiple extension like .co.uk, this would be the way to do that. However, you'd need to have a list of them that you'd want to iterate on in order to find them or else create a regex that would find them within the list of splits.